# Ground on "type E" plug adapter

Tags: france, power

I brought to the US a French [Belkin F7C01008 power-strip](http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0042YQ4Q4?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00) with a ["type E" plug](http://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeE.htm). I got an adapter for US plugs, however it lacks the "male grounding pin" that the French type E plug expects. Although the plug does fit, and the adapter can be used, the power-strip LED indicates it's not grounded.

Does an adapter for type E plugs to US plugs with a male grounding pin exist, and will it allow my power-strip to be grounded? I can't seem to find one anywhere online.

Comment: If this is for permanant use I would advise avoiding the adaptor and just cutting the plug off and fitting an american one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an adapter](http://www.110220volts.com/USA-Plug.html) that does exactly what you want (it is type F, but type E will also fit AFAIK).

If you can not get that adapter for any reason, you can always buy a separate [grounding pin](http://img.directindustry.com/images_di/photo-g/grounding-pins-11746-2282663.jpg) and install it (at your own risk), I would ask an electrician to do it.

Comment: Hmm, I would buy such an adapter elsewhere. The frontal photograph on the page that you linked to shows a type E Pin (France), but the photograph taken sideways looks more like type F.  Unless the power strip works in both types of plugs (which it may, but the photo on Amazon linked to by the OP doesn't show the plug), it is safer to have the correct adapter such that grounding is supported.

Comment: As I understand it plugs that work with the german or french system but not both are pretty much unheard of on new equipment.

Comment: Having been to france recently I can say that while equipment nearly always has the hybrid plugs, things like extension leads, double adapters etc often don't.